# Using :not selector with $(this)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following line which works OK

```
$("#myDiv img:not(:eq(0))").hide();
```

I want to write a similar line but using "this". So:

```
$(this":not(:eq(0))").hide();
```

But that doesn't work... Any ideas where it's gone wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The other answers are forgetting an important point - `this` is most likely in some event callback, and is likely a **single** element, so it is **always** the first element in the selection (`:eq(0)`).

Therefore each the following equivalent snippets will **never hide anything**:

```
$(this).not(':eq(0)').hide();
$(this).filter(':gt(0)').hide();
$(this).slice(1).hide();
```

I am only guessing the OP's intent here, but the code should most likely be:

```
if ($(this).index('#myDiv img') > 0) $(this).hide();
```

Comment: I probably should have been clearer in my question but you're exactly right and your answer does the job a treat. Thanks

Comment: `$('#myDiv img:not(:eq(0))').hide();` is pretty much the same thing so I guess I was right with my original approach.

Comment: @Tom it's *slightly* different but probably works for your use case. The difference is that your original code will hide every `img` that's not the first, instead of just the one the event was triggered on.

Answer (score 6):

try `.not(selector)` http://api.jquery.com/not/

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should work:

```
$(this).not(":eq(0)").hide();
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you should be using the `:gt()` selector

> Description: Select all elements at an index greater than index within the matched set.

try:

```
$(this).find(":gt(0)").hide();
```

or:

```
$(":gt(0)", this).hide();
```

---

isn't `:not(:eq(0))` a clunky way of writing `:gt(0)`?

Answer (score 0):

```
$($(this).selector + ":not(:eq(0))").hide();
```

Comment: `$(this)` has no selector - it merely wraps an existing DOM node.